# Наполнение массива в java несколькими переменными

Tags: java, массивы

Допустим, есть 3 переменные:

```java
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = 3;
```

Нужно заполнить ими массив размерностью 10, так, чтобы каждая из переменных встречалась хотя бы дважды. Как это реализовать при помощи одного оператора и не используя рандом?

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] arr = new int[]{a,b,c,a,b,c,a,b,c,a};
```

Один оператор

Comment: Логично, в следующий раз буду лучше думать над формулировкой вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Например, можно сделать так:

```java
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = 3;

int[] arr = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10)
        .map(i -> i % c == 0 ? c : i % b == 0 ? b : a)
        .toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
// [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2]
```